# LocalBroadcastManager only with support library?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-support-library, localbroadcastmanager

In my Android app I want to broadcast some notifications. In the `MainActivity` I register `BroadcastReceiver` which handles messages but as I understand it is not recommended to use global `BroadcastReceiver` if I do not want to send messages out of the app. Instead of this a `LocalBroadcastManager` or `Handler` should be used. In my case `LocalBroadcastManager` is more suitable but according to documentation it is part of a support library.

My app supports only Android 4 and 5 so I am not using support library. Is there a way how to use `LocalBroadcastManager` without support library? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My app supports only Android 4 and 5 so I am not using support
>   library. Is there a way how to use LocalBroadcastManager without
>   support library?

No there is not. As the `ViewPager` and another small amounts of Widget/Classes, `LocalBroadcastManager` is part only of the support library

Answer (score 0):

Try using `localbroadcastmanager` Maven artifact. It doesn't need "support-v4".

```
implementation 'com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0'
```